В единственном или множественном числе должен быть глагол в таком предложении?
Главным образом поражается стенка мочевого пузыря, а также мочеточники в нижней трети.

Почему не написать: в первую очередь поражаются стенка мочевого пузыря и мочеточники нижней трети? Зачем лишние союзы и подчинения, и "главным образом" - сомнительный оборот в таком тексте, потому что образ - это "представление о", а не сам факт того, что что-то произошло, предполагающий четкость выражения, а неведения тени на плетень.

Выбор множественного числа делается по стилевой характеристике текста, так как в медицинской литературе требуется согласование по смыслу, а не по форме:
Главным образом поражаются стенка мочевого пузыря, а также мочеточники в нижней трети.
Пояснение
Отношения между подлежащими при наличии союза А ТАКЖЕ однородные.


Сказуемое, стоящее после однородных подлежащих, ставится, как правило,
в форме множественного числа. Например: Жара и засуха стояли более
трех недель. Сказуемое, стоящее перед однородными подлежащими, обычно
ставится в форме единственного числа. Например: Мне нравится его
спокойствие и ровная речь.

